# Difference between Query

Tags: sql

I have three Tables
**TAB01**

```
CAMPO1 | CAMPO2
 01    |ONE
 02    |TWO
 03    |THREE
 04    |FOUR
```

**TAB02**

```
CAMPO1 | CAMPO2
 01    |ONE
 02    |TWO
 03    |THREE
```

**TAB03**

```
CAMPO1 | CAMPO2
 01    |ONE
 02    |TWO
 03    |THREE
```

when i execute query

```sql
SELECT TAB01.CAMPO1,TAB02.CAMPO2
FROM TAB01
  LEFT JOIN TAB02 ON TAB02.CAMPO1=TAB01.CAMPO1
  INNER JOIN TAB03 ON TAB03.CAMPO1=TAB02.CAMPO1
```

the results is

```
CAMPO1 | CAMPO2
 01|01
 02|02
 03|03
```

when i execute query

```
SELECT TAB01.CAMPO1,T1.CAMPO2
FROM TAB01
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT TAB02.CAMPO1,TAB02.CAMPO2 FROM_TAB02 
  INNER JOIN TAB03 ON TAB03.CAMPO1=TAB02.CAMPO1) T1 ON T1.CAMPO1=TAB01.CAMPO1
```

the results is

```
CAMPO1 | CAMPO2
01|01
02|02
03|03
04|NULL
```

Why?

Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: please format your question so that it is easier to read. you can use code blocks etc. to format the text. see here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two queries are:

```
SELECT TAB01.CAMPO1, TAB02.CAMPO2
FROM TAB01 LEFT JOIN 
     TAB02 ON
     TAB02.CAMPO1 = TAB01.CAMPO1 INNER JOIN 
     TAB03
     ON TAB03.CAMPO1 = TAB02.CAMPO1

SELECT TAB01.CAMPO1, T1.CAMPO2
FROM TAB01 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TAB02.CAMPO1,TAB02.CAMPO2
      FROM_TAB02 INNER JOIN
           TAB03
           ON TAB03.CAMPO1 = TAB02.CAMPO1
     ) T23  -- changed the alias to something more reasonable
     ON T23.CAMPO1 = TAB01.CAMPO1
```

These are quite different in terms of the rows that are in the result set.

For the first query the logic is:

- Keep all rows in in `TAB01` even if there are no matches in `TAB02`.
- Then the final result set only has rows where `TAB02` and `TAB03` match.
- Because `NULL`s do not match the final `INNER JOIN` condition, the query is essentially all `INNER JOIN`s.

The second query has the logic:

- Keep all rows in `TAB01` even if there are no matches in `T23`.
- Join `TAB02` and `TAB03` so there are only matching rows.

There is no additional filtering on `TAB01`.

As a general rule with outer joins, I recommend:

- Use `INNER JOIN`s first, if there are any.  These can filter the data.
- Then use `LEFT JOIN`s to keep all the rows from the preceding table or tables.
- Once you use `LEFT JOIN`, do not use `INNER JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`.

`FULL JOIN`s are rarely needed.  And I almost never use `RIGHT JOIN`s.